# Flutter : Unity widget not starting when run

Tags: flutter, unity-game-engine

I using [flutter_unity_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_unity_widget) for hybrid app.

Unity widget not starting, from video can see the scene stuck, I have to go background and return to foreground , then only the scene start load

[click here for video](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6957533/157610951-eb8b8ce2-6fb6-467e-a421-7f88a39af0ad.mp4)

Code are same with official provided

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_unity_widget/flutter_unity_widget.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  static final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey =
      GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  late UnityWidgetController _unityWidgetController;
  double _sliderValue = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  // Communcation from Flutter to Unity
  void setRotationSpeed(String speed) {
    _unityWidgetController.postMessage(
      'Cube',
      'SetRotationSpeed',
      speed,
    );
  }

  // Communication from Unity to Flutter
  void onUnityMessage(message) {
    print('Received message from unity: ${message.toString()}');
  }

  // Callback that connects the created controller to the unity controller
  void onUnityCreated(controller) {
    this._unityWidgetController = controller;
  }

  // Communication from Unity when new scene is loaded to Flutter
  void onUnitySceneLoaded(SceneLoaded? sceneInfo) {
    print('Received scene loaded from unity: ${sceneInfo!.name}');
    print('Received scene loaded from unity buildIndex: ${sceneInfo.buildIndex}');
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Unity Flutter Demo'),
        ),
        body: Card(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          ),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              UnityWidget(
                  onUnityCreated: onUnityCreated,
                  onUnityMessage: onUnityMessage,
                  onUnitySceneLoaded: onUnitySceneLoaded,
                  fullscreen: true,
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 20,
                left: 20,
                right: 20,
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 10,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                        child: Text("Rotation speed:"),
                      ),
                      Slider(
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _sliderValue = value;
                          });
                          setRotationSpeed(value.toString());
                        },
                        value: _sliderValue,
                        min: 0,
                        max: 20,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution , simple do like this on `onUnityCreated`

```
    void onUnityCreated(controller) {
      unityWidgetController = controller;
      unityWidgetController.pause();
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1),(){
        unityWidgetController.resume();
      });
    }
```